# Angular 2 - Exchanging data among components (without services)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Using services to share global data looks good. But I believe that such practice is not the best way just to share data with others components. It's okay to store globals in a service such as logged user, settings or anything whose many components needs to retrieve the data.

I prefer some kind of direct communication when a component need to send data to another. The documentation about this is very scant and in many cases, applies to outdated versions of Angular 2 Beta.

I'm trying to create something very raw to place in a public repo for people with same need, but facing difficulty with the emitter.

I can't find a way to make one component "listen" the event of the another component when I use EventEmitter.

The generic example bellow basically is about a child component send data to the parent. The end result must be the feedback variable showing a "boom" when the user types "fire".

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ParentComponent} from './parent.component'
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
directives : [ParentComponent],
template: `<h1>My App</h1>
<parent-component></parent-component>
`
})
export class AppComponent { 

}
```

parent.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ChildComponent} from './child.component'
@Component({
selector: 'parent-component',
directives : [ChildComponent]
template: `<p>I'm the parent component</p>
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]="theModel">
<p>feedback: {{feedback}}</p><!--THIS IS WHERE THE BOOM MUST APPEAR-->
<child-component txt="{{theModel}}"></child-component>
`
})
export class ParentComponent { 
   theModel;
}
```

child.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, EventEmitter,Output, Injectable}    from 'angular2/core';
@Injectable()
@Component({
selector: 'child-component',
template: `<p>I'm the child component</p>
`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges { 
@Input() txt: string;
@Output() aim: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    var t = changes['txt'].currentValue;
    if(t == 'fire') {
        console.log('Fire !!!');
        this.kill.aim("booom !!!");
    }
}
}
```

I need to find a way to capture the event emitted by the child component.
I saw few example of similar needs, but looks like angular 2 you have many ways to do the same thing, so usually the examples just applies to one scenario - That's why I'm creating something generic with no link to any need in particular. By the way, I'm not sure if a child emitting something is really the best way. Feel free to collaborate with better approaches.

Comment: This scenario is discussed (and has working code) in the Angular docs, in the Component Interaction cookbook: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register an action to an event of a child component using `(aim)="feedback=$event"`

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ChildComponent} from './child.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  directives : [ChildComponent]
  template: `
<p>I'm the parent component</p>
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]="theModel">
<p>feedback: {{feedback}}</p><!--THIS IS WHERE THE BOOM MUST APPEAR-->
<child-component txt="{{theModel}}" (aim)="feedback=$event"></child-component>`
})
export class ParentComponent { 
   feedback;
   theModel;
}
```

You emit an event for a parent to listen to using `this.aim.emit(someValue)`

```ts
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, EventEmitter,Output, Injectable}    from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `<p>I'm the child component</p>`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges { 
  @Input() txt: string;
  @Output() aim: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    var t = changes['txt'].currentValue;
    if(t == 'fire') {
        console.log('Fire !!!');
        // this.kill.aim("booom !!!");
        this.aim.emit("boom");
    }
  }
}
```

More details https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding

Comment: Ty, Günter and Micronyks ! the solution is very simple ! I wish I could find documentation with samples before. Well, I placed all the help provided (with Credits for both) on GIT , so I hope this sample can help many others developers. ty ! https://github.com/marcojr/angular2-components-sharing-data

Answer (score 1):

[Simple example - EventEmitter](http://plnkr.co/edit/nAeepqZpYkAeJQvsYzyU?p=preview)

**parent.ts**

```
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]="theModel">
<child-component txt="{{theModel}}" (aim)=onEdit($event)></child-component>

onEdit(arg){  // this function is optional you my also try what Gunter has suggested.
   console.log(arg);
   this.feedback=arg;
}
```

**child.ts**

```
@Input() txt: string;
@Output() aim: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
var t = changes['txt'].currentValue;
 if(t == 'fire') {
    console.log('Fire !!!');
       this.aim.emit("boom");
 }
}
...
```

**Note**: *you can pass object as well demonstrated in above link*.